# How to disable on DNN 5 new user registration emails to admin?

Tags: dotnetnuke-5

Is there a way to turn off the email notification to the admin for new user registrations on DNN 5?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to edit the ADMIN user on DNN "user management" and change the email address to another, i.e. an alias.

Then you can create a rule on your mail client.

This solution is valid for old DNN installation 5.X.